# to college, not to university / to college and not university

Tags: sentence-meaning

Am I right that both sentences are correct, but there is a nuance that in the first sentence its end is a specifying question, and in the second one its end is for contrast? Are they both pretty informal, or the first one is less informal?

> Why did you decide to go to college, **not to university**?
>
> Why did you decide to go to college **and not university**?

Comment: Note that in the US this question would not make sense as the two are now entirely synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both of these are correct and they have the same meaning. Neither one strikes me as informal.